# as3 create function for each item (in array?)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop, drop-down-menu, flash-cs6

I have a movieclip called *colorDDMenu* that contains a single button called *color*_ *btn* and a movieclip called *menu*_ *mc* containing 4 more buttons.

The idea is that the user will click on the color button and the movieclip containing the 4 buttons will appear,  so they can click on one of the 4 buttons to select a color. In addition to the color drop-down menu I will have 12 more drop-down menus for other attributes (streak, hardness, heft, etc.).

So far this is my code for the color drop-down menu:

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    menu_mc.visible = false;

    hover_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, drop);

    function drop(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        menu_mc.visible = true;
        hover_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, drop);
        hover_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, up);
    }

    function up(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        menu_mc.visible = false;
        hover_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, up)
        hover_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, drop);
    }
```

and it successfully opens and closes the menu like I intended.

Closed:

[image]

and Opened:

[image]

Now to the point!

I'm trying to find an efficient way to apply this drop-down method to 12 more drop-down menus. As opposed to typing in this code for every single menu.

I was wondering if I might be able to do this via methods of using an Array and for loop, which creates this function for every menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an array. There's no need to create a function for each menu; just link each button to its menu and use that when clicking.

You could also make a class to achieve the same and keeping it cleaner.

Comment: The answer is incomprehensible to an amateur, while true in its essence. I'd advise you to add an example describing a basic method of how it could be done, so the question author will get your example and apply it to his situation.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short tutorial for this on my blog. The key is to use a dictionary object to keep track of what should happen when a button is clicked, to associate data with a button.

Here is a link to that tutorial:
http://plasticsturgeon.com/2010/06/my-favorite-menu-part-2-the-dictionary-object/

And here is the code from that tutorial:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Zachary Foley
 */
public class SimpleXMLMenu extends Sprite
{
    private var loader:URLLoader;
    private var xmldata:XML;
    private var buttonData:Dictionary;
    private var _currentSelection:PrettyButton;
    private var _selectedData:String;

    public function SimpleXMLMenu()
    {
        // Create a loader to bring in the xml
        loader = new URLLoader();
        // create a dictionary to store the data associted with each pretty button.
        // don't bother those pretty buttons with the details.
        buttonData = new Dictionary();
        loadXML()
    }

    private function loadXML():void
    {
        // start the XML load.
        loader.load(new URLRequest("MenuData.xml"));
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoaded)
    }

    private function onXMLLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        // get the data from the loader and cast it as XML
        xmldata = new XML(loader.data);
        // make a bunch of buttons from the xml
        makeButtons()
    }

    private function makeButtons():void
    {
        // The schema for the loop will change based on your xml structure.
        for (var i:int = 0; i &lt; xmldata.menu.button.length(); i++)
        {
            // grab the xml for the button
            var xml:XML = xmldata.menu.button[i];
            // create a new button and set the label to the XML label.
            var b:PrettyButton = new PrettyButton(xml.label);
            // store the xml data in our dictionary to be looked up
            // when the button is clicked.
            buttonData[b] = xml;
            b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMenuClick)
            b.y = this.height;
            addChild(b);
            addChild(b);
        }
    }

    private function handleMenuClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (_currentSelection != null) {
            _currentSelection.selected = false;
        }
        var buttonClicked:PrettyButton = e.target as PrettyButton;
        _currentSelection = buttonClicked;
        _currentSelection.selected = true;
        _selectedData = buttonData[e.target].content;
    }

    public function get selectedData():String { return _selectedData; }

}
```

}